# Free product with amalgamation of surjective homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be any group and $N_1,N_2$ be normal subgroups.
Then $N_1N_2$ is anormal subgroups too.
Is $G/(N_1N_2)$ the free product with amalgamation of the diagram
$G/N_1 \leftarrow G \rightarrow G/N_2$?

Im trying to check the universal property, if i have a
morphism $j_1 \colon G/N_1 \rightarrow Q$ making the diagram
commute, then $G\rightarrow Q$ is an homomorphism vanishing at $N_1$ and $N_2$
then we have a unique homomorphism $G/(N_1N_2)\rightarrow Q$.

Is this argument clear or im doing something wrong?

Comment: Why do you write $\;N_1\color{red}+N_2\;$ ? Is by chance the group $\;G\;$ abelian (and thus the normality thing is trivial), or what's the reason for the additive notation?

Comment: Im not assuming $G$ is abelian, the additive notation is only used in this case?

Comment: 140676 In 99% of the cases (when doing cohomology there are cases...). This is why I think this is very, very unusual *without further* data. Anyway, why do you think the quotient group $\;G/(N_1+N_2)\;$ would be a free product with amalgamation? And amalgamation...over **what** ?

Comment: Im trying to prove that $G/(N_1+N_2)$ is the push-out of the diagram $G/N_1 \leftarrow G \rightarrow G/N_2$. In this case, the free product is $G/N_1 \cdot G/N_2$ and the amalgamation over the subgroup generated by elements $p_1(g)-p_2(g)$ where $p_1\colon G\rightarrow G/N_1$ and $p_2\colon G \rightarrow G/N_2$ are the corresponding quotients.

Comment: without further data the claim seems to be blatantly false: a free product with amalgamation over the trivial subgroup )i.e. a free product...just like that) s.t. that neither of the two factors (or more than two) is the trivial group is always infinite, yet I'm sure you can find counterexamples where the above quotient group is finite...

Comment: I changed the additive notation. I still think that $G/N_1N_2$ hold the universal property of the push-out, then it should be the free product with the amalgamation given by the subgroup generated by $p_1(g)p_2(g)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your argument is correct.

There may be some confusion due to the fact that "free product with amalgamation" is almost always used, in group theory, in the case when both structural homomorphisms are injective. But in the case of surjective homomorphisms you indeed get $G/N_1N_2$, by an immediate use of the universal property.